# How to add Currency Symbols in pdf, generated by my application?

Tags: android, pdf, currency

I want to add currency symbols in pdf report, generated by my android application. String symbols i am adding to the file... but its not displaying. Is there any solution? Do i need to use any fonts or encoding for that?

Comment: question is not clear at all, PDF supports unicode symbols; what's the problem? which library do you use?

Comment: i am using itextpdf library

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use just a few currency signs then you may use a walk around for for some symbols, for example for the Euro sign in PDF using the built-in pdf font Helvetica with the 1252 code page:

```
  BaseFont helvetica = BaseFont.createFont("Helvetica", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
  Font font = new Font(helvetica, 12, Font.NORMAL);
  Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Euro symbol:  20\u20ac.", font);
  document.add(chunk);
```

But if you are looking to support all currency symbols then you should use the unicode enabled font (like *Arial Unicode MS*) and embed it into output PDF. You may find the complete list of Unicode currency symbols at [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf).